# How to merge results of multiple viscircles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry

I'm trying to plot a circle in a function using viscircles, and then come back to that function later on to plot another circle like the figure shown below:

[image: Multiple circles]

At the moment, I can only plot single circles using these lines of code:

```
figure
center = [numberX numberY];
xlim([-0.1 10.1])
ylim([-0.1 10.1])
axis square
artwork = viscircles(center,size,'Color',colorControl)
```

After plotting the first `viscircles`, control rolls back over to a prompts function to get data for the next `viscircles`, but when it comes back around to plotting, the original `viscircles` is overwritten, even when I tried using `hold on`. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you edit the question to add more lines of the code? That could help others suggest something.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng! The code worked great for new adding new circles. I know I didn't make it very clear in the question, but I'm actually trying to get multiple colors of circles plotted. With your code, every time a new circle is added all the circles become the new color. Is there a way around this? I tried copying the format you used for the centers and sizes variables, but Matlab wasn't too happy about that.

Comment: @LouisRichard I'll modify my post soon. I'm not at home right now. Glad the code worked so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`viscircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/viscircles.html) by default will flush the figure and draw only the circles specified by the inputs you provide it so `hold on` will not work.

What you can do instead is keep **appending** to your data so that the original data is displayed followed by a new circle each time you prompt for new data.

As such, do something like this.  Assuming that you have a function called `getNewCenter` that returns a new center, the size of the circle and the colour, and matrices that contain the centers to display as well as their sizes:

```
centers = [];
sizes = []; % Matrices that contain the centers and sizes

while true % Keep iterating...

    [numberX, numberY, size, colorControl] = getNewCenter; % Get new center, size and colour

    % Add to the data
    centers = [centers; numberX numberY];
    sizes = [sizes; size];

    % Plot the circles
    xlim([-0.1 10.1]);
    ylim([-0.1 10.1]);
    axis square;
    artwork = viscircles(centers, sizes, 'Color', colorControl);
end
```